# Framework7 Cordova Ajax Post 503 service unavailable

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am new to Cordova and Framework7 but can get along since it is similar with jQuery but I am stuck with this issue. I was using an external url link which is an API to login and I don't have any control of the API which means I cannot edit or modify it.

I tried to test it using Postman and it's working fine. I tried installing and using this extension [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) but still getting the result of `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.` I am using a [Ripple extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) to properly run my application.

HTML:

```
<form id="login" class="ajax-submit" method="post">
<input type="email" name="input[email]" class="required email login-email" placeholder="Email Address" />
<input type="password" name="input[password]" class="required login-password" placeholder="Password" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function login_submit() {
    $$('#login').on('submit', function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        if (!$form.valid())
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: api_url + '/api/login',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (typeof data.failed != 'undefined' && data.failed == '1') {
                    myApp.alert(data.msg_error, 'Error');
                } else {
                    $form.find('button').text('Sign in');
                    Specifier = data;

                    mainView.router.loadPage('featured.html');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status) {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(xhr));
                console.log('ErrorStatus: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
            }
        })

        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

I use `cordova run browser` to run the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a cordova or Framework7 issue, that is a problem of your server.

Comment: thanks for the response @Joerg. I am still trying to get an access to the client's server so that I can check the issue or problem including the API.